# How to add inline images using gatsby-image?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, gatsby

### Desired

I have been trying to query and display some images with max width of 350px and for tablets and above I would like to display them `inline-block`, each next to the other and wrap if they fill their parent div.

---

### Issue

The custom CSS styles are applied however the images are not displayed inline or not rendered at all.

---

### Current results

I have tried each of the `display: inline-block`, `float: left`, `overflow-wrap: break-word` and `flex-wrap: wrap` but every time the images are being displayed as `block` or not rendered at all.

---

Here is my component:

```js
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"
import Img from "gatsby-image"

import AccessoryStyles from "./accessory.module.css"

const Accessory = () => (
<StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        allFile(
          filter: {
            extension: { regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/" }
            relativeDirectory: { eq: "Lanka-Belt" }
          }
        ) {
          edges {
            node {
              childImageSharp {
                sizes(maxWidth: 350) {
                  ...GatsbyImageSharpSizes_withWebp
                  presentationWidth
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => {
      const images = data.allFile.edges.map((image, index) => (
        <div className={AccessoryStyles.imageContainer}>
          <Img
            key={index}
            style={{
              maxWidth: image.node.childImageSharp.sizes.presentationWidth,
            }}
            sizes={image.node.childImageSharp.sizes}
          />
        </div>
      ))
      return {images}
     }
    }
 />
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and here is my custom styles from the `accessory.module.css`:

```
.image-container {
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

[image: image is being displayed as block while not wrapping]

I have been searching for 2 days now both on StackOverflow and Github issues of gatbsy and gatbsy-image with no luck whatsoever.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: display: inline-block!important did you try?

Comment: have you tried changing the display of the img also and not just the container? so ... `.image-container img { /*styles*/ }`

Comment: I apologise guys for the confusion I wasn't clear on the results I'm getting.The styles are applied however the images are not rendered at all or they don't wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have managed to find the reason why they wouldn't render. Images with `display` property of `inline-block` would not render if the `width` CSS property is not specified.

So after passing the data to the `<Img />` component, I have set the `width` and `display` styles directly on the `<Img />` component itself. So the render function now looks like this:

```
render={data => {
  const images = data.allFile.edges.map((image, index) => (
    <div className={AccessoryStyles.imageContainer}>
      <Img
        key={index}
        style={{
          maxWidth: image.node.childImageSharp.sizes.presentationWidth,
          width: image.node.childImageSharp.sizes.presentationWidth,
          display: "inline-block",
        }}
        sizes={image.node.childImageSharp.sizes}
      />
    </div>
  ))
  return {images}
 }
}
```

- You might want to pass a `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` on the **parent** element of these images to look a bit nicer ;)